# Can I open several files with the same extension without typing the extension through cmd?

Tags: files, file-format

I got a few files to open and they are all in a folder filled with files with the same extension. My question is as the title says, but I'll provide an example:

`yourprogram <filename1>.ext <filename2>.ext .... <filenameN>.ext &`

Could be any program that opens these files, but the point is that I want to avoid typing their extension. Are there any short codes for just writing the file names and use something like `*.ext*` at the end?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean that you can't glob because there are files with different extensions with the same names apart from the extension, or you don't want to open ALL the files with that extension?

Comment: The latter, sorry for not being precise enough. It's easy to open all of them:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple as this:

```
yourprog {file1,file2,file3}.png
```

Note that this is intended only for files in current  directory